# Unix ksh alias parameter for multiple commands?

Tags: unix, alias, profile, ksh

I did a research and found some solutions but none of them worked for me... Maybe could you help me ?
I've 2 exec : prog1 and prog2. (ksh)
I would like to run them, at the same time with the alias "e"

So I did this:

> e TEST

It should be translated by

> prog1 TEST
>
> prog2 TEST

I tried :

> ALIAS e='prog1 $1; prog2 $1'

OR

> e() {
>
> prog1 $1 | prog2 $1
>
> }

Without success.

Do you have any solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function should work but you separate commands with a semicolon, not a pipe. Or just put them on separate lines - newline is a valid command separator, too.

```
e() {
    prog1 $1
    prog2 $1
}
```

You should properly have double quotes around $1, and in the general case, you should cope if there is more than one parameter; use `"$@"` to pass on the entire parameter list, or loop over the parameters:

```
e() {
    local a
    for a; do
        prog1 "$a"
        prog2 "$a"
    done
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You say 'run them at the same time', then you need to run one (or both) in the background.

```
alias e='prog1 $1 &; prog2 $1 &;'
```

alias will not be recognized when capitalized.

Aliases do no accept arguments, use a function.

```
 function e { prog1 "$1" & ; prog2 "$1" & ; }
```

Tested with

```
function e { sleep "$1" & ; sleep "$1" & ; }
```

output

```
/home/shellter:>e 7
[1]     384512
[2]     267648
/home/shellter:>jobs
[2] +  Running                 e 7
[1] -  Running                 e 7
/home/shellter:>jobs
[2] +  Done                    e 7
[1] -  Done                    e 7
```

Comment: The use of a semicolon after the ampersand is superfluous; the ampersand is a command separator in itself (with the additional background semantics).